# Can you have collection level permissions in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, permissions

Can you have collection level permissions in MongoDB?  Similar to table level permissions in a SQL database?

This is the only thing I could find on it.  Looks like an old ticket.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1105

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would ever need this. Care to elaborate?

Comment: For the same reason you'd want it in a SQL database: giving different stakeholders the ability to run queries against collections that they own, without allowing them access to other collections.  It's really important for many production uses of databases.

Comment: collection level permissions will be available in 2.6 (currently available in development releases 2.5.3 and 2.5.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not yet, MongoDB access control is currently only available at the database level.  Depending on your requirements, it might be an option to implement a security model in application code that controls access down to the collection level.

Comment: Hmm, ok, do you know if there's a timeline for when this might happen?

Comment: Sorry no, you could try to MongoDB mailing list, or adding your vote and comments to the JIRA ticket.

Comment: If you want this, go vote for the feature request: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1105

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming to this late (like I did), MongoDB now has support for collection-level authorization.

See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/