# How to manage users and collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Im triying to create users in a database in mongo, I want to lock the usage of te collections for some users, I'll give an example:

Lets say that I actually have a db with 3 collections:

Books,
Students,
Proffesors

And 3 users:

Librarian,
SecretaryManager,
Director

And I want the Librarian have r/w permissions just in Books, SecretaryManager r/w permissions in Students and Professors, and finally, Director that would have the same permissions as Librarian + SecretaryManager.

I've readed the documentation of mongo main website, im aware of using db.adduser, but I haven't find the way of doing this or I've miss something.

Need help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You would enforce this through your application not through mongodb, what librarian is gonna touch your database directly like that, in fact what end user would you want to touch your database like that?

Comment: Have you tried this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/ or http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/#db.addUser

Comment: @AbhishekGahlot yes, I've readed over it, but I dont understand well it, and I didn't found anything about limitating collections.

Comment: @Sammaye Its a requirement for the db, I must create that limits for that users in mongo(I don't like it too...), I need to know if this is possible.

Comment: I do not believe there is currently a way in mongodb to do collection level granularity, only database

Comment: Sammaye is correct. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7883649/1611791)

Comment: as I commented in the duplicate ticket - this feature is implemented in the current development branch (2.5.3 and 2.5.4) and will be in production release 2.6